# Can a DNS server consult another DNS for specific domain name extensions?

Tags: domain-name-system

For example, suppose I have multiple DNS servers under a private network which handle name resolutions for domains only hosted under said private network. Suppose also I use the name extension .wifi for domains hosted on the Wi-Fi.

When DNS1 gets a request for webservice.wifi, it should say to itself "I don't know how to resolve .wifi names, but I know DNS2 does," and then consults DNS2.

In essence, I want to have a top level DNS which resolves extensions, and then each extension has a dedicated DNS for full resolution.

Is this:

A) Possible for a private network?

B) Reasonable for a private network (e.g. any major security flaws, etc)?

Comment: You should not invent own TLDs as there's no guarantee they won't be allocated in the future.

Comment: I'd be pretty confident something like '.localwifi' wouldn't be allocated, then.

Comment: Alternatively, couldn't I append to a domain I already own?

Comment: Yes, that would be recommended. :)

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible.  But without stating which name server software and the existing configuration you use it is hard to give a definitive answer.

The venerable bind will use a syntax similar to:

```
zone "example.wifi" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 
         IP.address.of.DNS2 ; 
    };
};
```

Comment: Would that not bind specifically 'example.wifi'? The goal is scalability such that if a new .wifi name is added to DNS2, it does not need to be added to DNS1 because all DNS1 says is ".wifi is handled by DNS2, go there."

Comment: I'm most likely handling everything on EdgeMax included DNS, by the way. I didn't specify that because I'm more so looking for the concepts I need to research, rather than copy-and-paste solutions.

Comment: That works for everything below the example.wifi leaf in DNS and expands also to `.wifi` if you are so inclined.